# Save continuous historical stock data to pandas dataframe using python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to save historical data of metatrader5 for symbol 'EURUSD', trying to fetch single candle and append it to empty dataframe.

```
df = []
previous_time = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=59)
#print(previous_time)

def printit():
    threading.Timer(59.9, printit).start()
    data_1_min = pd.DataFrame(mt.copy_rates_range("EURUSD.", mt.TIMEFRAME_M1, previous_time, dt.now()))
    data_1_min['time'] = [dt.fromtimestamp(x).strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S") for x in data_1_min['time']]
    data_1_min['Timeframe'] = '5 Minute interval'
    #json_data = data_1_min.to_json(orient = 'records')
    #print(json_data)
    
printit()
```

Output received --

```
[{"time":"02-25-2022 20:56:00","open":1.12204,"high":1.12237,"low":1.12201,"close":1.12236,"tick_volume":84,"spread":0,"real_volume":0,"Timeframe":"5 Minute interval"},{"time":"02-25-2022 20:57:00","open":1.12237,"high":1.12249,"low":1.12223,"close":1.12223,"tick_volume":72,"spread":0,"real_volume":0,"Timeframe":"5 Minute interval"},{"time":"02-25-2022 20:58:00","open":1.1222,"high":1.12233,"low":1.12201,"close":1.12225,"tick_volume":72,"spread":0,"real_volume":0,"Timeframe":"5 Minute interval"},{"time":"02-25-2022 20:59:00","open":1.1222,"high":1.12293,"low":1.12214,"close":1.12282,"tick_volume":98,"spread":0,"real_volume":0,"Timeframe":"5 Minute interval"}]
```

But I want single frame as output to append and save in dataframe like

```
{"time":"02-25-2022 20:56:00","open":1.12204,"high":1.12237,"low":1.12201,"close":1.12236,"tick_volume":84,"spread":0,"real_volume":0,"Timeframe":"5 Minute interval"}
```

Comment: I have no idea how `mt.copy_rates_range` method is working but you'll have to limit the amount of data here.

Comment: It fetch data between two timeframes which we are going to pass